# SSIS package hang up at OLE DB Destination

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have a scheduled SSIS job, before it was executed w/o any problems. Today it stuck at `OLE DB Destination`, which is trying to populate records to the table on production server. I tried to change the connection which connects to our development server, the table schema on DEV is the same as the one on production server, no idea which it hang up for good.

I do not think table get locked because I could still query against the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue found: Out web user was trying to pulling data from a view that contains that table, after I manually killed that process, the data keeps going through.

Comment: If you want to prevent this in the future, you can define the view to use WITH NOLOCK when querying the table that got locked.